# ASP.NET Validate membership email from ClientSideEvents and WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have ASPxGridview and i want to check if email already registered before or not in editform using ClientSideEvents.

Any help to resolve this problem ?

### aspx section

this is the javascript section

```
function OnEmailValidation(s, e) {
            var error = "";
            var tfld = trim(e.value);
            var illegalChars = /^\w+([-+.'''']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
            if (!illegalChars.test(tfld)) {
                $get("spanEmail").innerHTML = "invalid email";

            } else {
                PageMethods.CheckEmail(e.value.toString(), OnCheckEmail);

                // how to check OnCheckEmail before continue
                //if(email already registered) {
                  // return false
                //}

                $get("spanEmail").innerHTML = "";
            }
            return true;
        }

function OnCheckEmail(unavailable) {
        if (unavailable == true) {
            $get("spanEmail").innerHTML = "already registered";
            $get("spanEmail").style.color = "red";
        }
        else if (unavailable != true) {
            $get("spanEmail").innerHTML = "Available";
            $get("spanEmail").style.color = "#76EB69";
        }
    }
```

### aspx.cs

```
col_Email.PropertiesTextEdit.ClientSideEvents.Validation = "OnEmailValidation";
grid.Columns.Add(col_Email);

[WebMethod]
public static bool CheckEmail(string email)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    if (Membership.FindUsersByEmail(email) != null)
    {
        if (Membership.FindUsersByEmail(email).Count <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

This is my final code after the 
[Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169195/filip)
advice but i have mini problem:

When i use 

(async: false) and cntr.SetIsValid(false);

the control doesn't apply the action

but If i use

(async: true) and cntr.SetIsValid(false);

the control apply the action

Why ?

I want to use async: false

```
function OnEmailValidation(s, e) {
var illegalChars = /^\w+([-+.'''']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
var spanEmail = document.getElementById("spanEmail");

var obj = GetObj('txt_Email');
var cntr = aspxGetControlCollection().Get(obj.id);

if (!illegalChars.test(e.value)) { 
    spanEmail.innerHTML = "Invalid Email";
    spanEmail.style.color = "red";

    cntr.SetIsValid(false);

} else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "myweb_service.asmx/CheckEmail",
        data: "{'email':'" + e.value.toString() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            if (res.d == "true") {
                spanEmail.innerHTML = "Email register before";
                spanEmail.style.color = "red";

                cntr.SetIsValid(false);
            }
            if (res.d == "false") {
                spanEmail.innerHTML = "Available";
                spanEmail.style.color = "#76EB69";

                cntr.SetIsValid(true);
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to call PageMethods (replace `PageMethods.CheckEmail` call with this code):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "<PageName>.aspx/CheckEmail",
    data: "{" + e.value.toString() + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
        if (res.d)
            return false;
    }
});
```

Replace `PageName` with your page name.
Be careful with synchronous (`async: false`) ajax calls. They will block your page until request finishes.
If `res.d` doesn't return result or you just want detailed explanation of posted code check these links:

- [Using jQuery to directly call aspnet ajax page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
- [A breaking change between versions of aspnet ajax](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)

Comment: Finaly it Works, thanks alot
after many hours to understand jQuery, it's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a web service on the server side that will check if the email already exists. Then you will use JavaScript AJAX (preferably a library like jQuery or Prototype) to query the web service during your validation method.

it will be a good deal of work to get it all set up. Good luck. See one of these links for more information:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb532367.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx

Comment: When i run the project in the topic which you told me


function OnClickGreetings() {
    var greetings = helloWorldProxy.Greetings();
    alert(greetings);
}

the alert doesn't wait the webmethod to respond
the alert display [Object]

I want the message wait for the Greetings() return with value.